# Kernel IPsec SA database: FIFO instead of LIFO

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, ipsec

When processing an IP packet, the kernel looks into the security policy (SP) database to determine whether it is to be protected with IPsec. If the identifiers of the packet (e.g. IP addresses, etc.) match an SP entry, the kernel searches for an appropriate Security Association (SA) in the corresponding database, containing the algorithms, keys and so on.

Now, the Linux kernel apparently takes always the most recently estblished matching SA (i.e. using LIFO). Is there a way (config file, command, etc.) to change this to FIFO? I am working on a solution, where I really want to "use up old SAs" before generating new ones.

Comment: I don't see how changing from LIFO to FIFO will change whether you find a match or not.  You'd only generate a new SA if you didn't find an existing one.

Comment: I work on a solution where SAs time out really fast. As speed is crucial, I want to generate SAs in advance to speed up the handover. Immeditately using a newly generated SA is very inconvenient in this context.